# Why is NgRx not producing the expected state?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have imported NgRx into my application:

```
imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {})    
 ],
```

My reducers are registered in `/ngrx/reducers/index.ts` as shown:

```
import { ActionReducerMap } from "@ngrx/store";
import { HeroReducers } from "../home/hero/hero.reducers";

export interface State {};

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap <State> = {
    heroReducers:HeroReducers
}
```

HeroReducer is shown here:

```
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as heroActions from "./hero.actions";

const initialState = {
  heroSlides: [
    {
      img: "Screenshot from 2024-01-20 12-38-48.png",
      status: "active"
    },
  ]
}

export const HeroReducers = createReducer(initialState,
on(heroActions.StoreHero, (state, action) => { 
  console.log('Storesubjects.subjects', action)   
  return {
    ...state,
    // subjects: action.subjects,
  };
}),
)
```

The action file for the reducer is shown here:

```
import { createAction, props } from "@ngrx/store";

  export const StoreHero = createAction(
    '[Store Hero] Store Hero'
  )
```

I inject the store in my component as shown here:

```
constructor(
    private store:Store<{heroReducers}>
  ) {}
```

In ngOnInit of my component, I subscribe to the reducer as shown. I also dispatch a call to the reducer.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribeToReduxStores();  
    this.store.dispatch(StoreHero());
}

  private subscribeToReduxStores = () => {
    const hero$ = this.store.select((state) => {   
      console.log('state', state)   
      return state
   })

    hero$.subscribe(hero => {      
      // this.hero = hero;    
      console.log('hero', hero)                    
   })
 }
```

I get the following results of the console.log calls:

```
state {}
hero {}
state {}
```

The state is an empty object and does not contain the heroSlides array of the initialState of the HeroReducers.

Comment: If you're not seeing the log from the init, it seems like you don't have that reducer wired up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations that potentially fix your issue.

Your `initialState` for `HeroesReducer` does not have a type defined. You can define what shape is going to have this particular heroes `slice` like the following:

**heroes.reducer.ts**

```
export interface HeroState {
  slides: { img: string; status: string}[];
}

const initialState: HeroState = {
  slides: [];
}

export const HeroesReducers(initialState, ...);
```

Where you have your `ActionReducerMap`, there is an **empty** interface called `State`, I feel like you could use that one in order to wrap the whole store slices definition, like the following:

```
import {HeroState} from '../heroes/heroes.reducer.ts';

export interface State {
  heroes: HeroState; 
  villains: VillainsState; // you could add more slices here
  biography: BiographyState; // you could add more slices here
}
```

Having that, now you can inject your store with the proper data type as:

**some.component.ts**

```
import {State} from '../interfaces/store.interface.ts'; // this is just an example

  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {}
```

I feel like your current code fails to know what the store has since you are defining the store dataType as `Store<{heroReducers}>`, from where are you taking this `heroReducers`? Also, make sure to use **redux dev tools** browser extension to see what you have in the store initially, validating if the `heroes` slice is defined and also to see every action triggered and monitor what happens with the data.

Additionally, the callback function for `selecting` data from the store should be defined in the proper selectors file using `createSelector` function, for example, `heroes.selectors.ts` rather than having that logic in your component.

**heroes.selectors.ts**

```
export const selectHeroes = createSelector(state => state.heroes);
```

For more information about `selectors`, I recommend reading the official [docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors)

Comment: In addition to what was said above, you have no feature selector. You need a feature selector to get your slice of state. 

https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#selectors